# HTML5 Required property changes <select> option fonts to Times New Roman on Chrome

Tags: html, required

When adding the required property to a `<select>` element, when we submit the form the select options show up using the Times new Roman font.

I made a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h52ZV/). First click on the select but don't select anything, just notice the Arial font. Then click on the "GO" button and then on the select again after the required form denies you submission, you'll see the option fonts have changed.

I've tried forcing them with !important on `select option` but it doesn't work... any ideas?

This only occurs with Chrome.

Code:

```
<form method='post' action=''>
  <select id='select' required>
    <option value>Select stuff</option>
    <option value='1'>Test 123</option>
    <option value='2'>Test again 123</option>
    <option value='3'>Test more 123</option>
  </select>

  <button type='submit'>go</button>
</form>

body {
  font: 80%/1.5 Arial;
}

select option {
 font-family: Arial !important;
}
```

Comment: That looks like a bug in Chrome.

Comment: It's what I'm thinking, I'm about to post on the Chrome dev forum, trying to see if there might be a temporary solution though.

Comment: Aha finally someone else noticed this! I also suspect Chrome bug, thanks for sending it to them.

Comment: Bug also on Chromium/linux. Did somebody try Safari ?

Comment: FYI it's on their troubleshooting forums too now: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/windows/cSRmYiHKrIk

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your .js:

```
$(document).ready(Inicio);

function Inicio()
{   
   $('#select').live("mouseover",function()
    {
       $('select option').css("font-family","Arial");        
    }); 
}
```